# Did Christopher Columbus stay at a Lodge in Cordoba?

Tags: christopher-columbus, george-washington, lodge, inn

In the United States, we have many Inns where it is said that "George Washington slept here".  Washington's stays at various Inns across the Northeastern United States are likely to be historically accurate and verifiable since Washington lived 200 plus years ago and the availability of such documents regarding Washington's lodgings across the Northeast, are probably in moderate-heavy supply-(due to the short chronological distance of Washington's time when compared with our time).

However, in the case of Christopher Columbus, we are talking about a person who lived 500 plus years ago and so the chronological distance is longer when compared with our time-(and even compared with Washington's time). Since the chronological distance is longer and greater, the task of verifying aspects of Columbus' biography is increasingly complex and challenging.

As part of Andalusian lore, it is widely believed that Christopher Columbus stayed at an existing Hotel in the city of Cordoba called, "Hacienda Posada De Vallina"-(specifically, in Rm. # 204), which is also footsteps from the city's most famous structure, the Mezquita/Cathedral. The Hotel was originally the Home of a Moorish Nobleman, though it was converted into a Lodge/"Posada", shortly after Cordoba fell to the Reconquista Christian Armies in the Late Middle Ages.  Part of the Hotel's History includes the claim Christopher Columbus lodged here-(a type of Andalusian version of, "George Washington slept here"), though for exactly how long.......that remains unknown.

Is there any genuine historical evidence-(besides Hotel tourism/promotional sites) which actually prove that Columbus stayed at this particular Hotel? Are there any historical records that can be accessed affirming Columbus' temporary residence at this existing and historic Andalusian Lodge?  There appears to be enough historical evidence proving that Columbus did have a House in the Spanish Canary Islands, which exists to this day; but can the same be said for this particular Hotel?

Comment: Generally, when people use words such as 'reputedly' or 'legend has it' without providing any evidence, it's either because it was made up or because the evidence has disappeared. However, I wouldn't mind being proved wrong in this case...

Answer (score 1):

So far all the links I've found about this hotel and Columbus start with "legend has it" or "they say". While Columbus stayed in Cordoba for some time, while trying to woo the spanish monarchs to fund his expedition, he was staying at the ["Convento de la Merced" (Mercy's convent)](http://sevilla.abc.es/hemeroteca/historico-29-06-2006/sevilla/Cordoba/cristobal-colon-nunca-estuvo-aqui_1422226244365.html) (link in spanish). Then he returned briefly to Portugal, and when he came back to Spain the kings have already conquered Granada, and there's where Columbus went.

He *could* have spent a night in Cordoba in a lodge, for sure, but the timing is problematic. According to the hotel sources, it became a lodge *after* the Granada campaign, while Columbus lived in Cordoba *during* said campaign. In any case, I have not found any evidence of this, and I suspect there is none to find.